# Best data structure for storing Employee objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a GUI that allows a user to create new employee objects and access their respective attributes. So far my program only allows for one object's information to be printed at a time:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Employee:

  def __init__(self, id, salary):
    self.id = id
    self.salary = salary

  def info(self):
    return "Employee ID: {}\nFull name:{}\nSalary:{}".format(self.id, self.full_name, self.salary)

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, Employee):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()  #Returns the parent object or the QMainWindow object
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("Employee builder")

    extractAction = QtGui.QAction("&Add Employee", self)
    extractAction.triggered.connect(self.create_employee)

    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

    self.home()

  def home(self):
    self.show()

  def create_employee(self):
    ID, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees id number:")
    pay, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees salary:")

    emp1 = Employee(ID, pay)
    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "Employee information:", emp1.info)

def run():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  GUI = Window()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

The next logic step as I see it would be to call a method which stores each newly created employee object so that a user can access the objects information based on the objects ID. In Python, would it pay to create a more advanced data structure like a hash table to store the objects? Or should I just be using a dictionary or a list (is a dictionary a hash table)? I am only doing this to learn Python and PyQt4 GUI's so I do not expect to be saving mega bytes of employee information or anything like that.

Comment: A dictionary is a hash table. Or, rather, something slightly fancier built on top of a hash table, but the point is that it’s exactly what you want to store things for lookup by key both efficiently and conveniently.

Comment: the structure does not depend on the GUI so do not use the PyQt4 tag please.

Comment: @abarnert Great, thanks!

Comment: Do you need this to be persistent across runs? If so, have you considered using a key-value database (even a simple one like `dbm/shelve`) or a relational database (like `sqlite3`), possibly through a simple ORM (like SqlAlchemy)? A dbm is basically a hash table on disk, and a relational database is basically a bunch of b trees on disk.

Comment: @abarnert Well I had thought about it. I thought about saving the objects information into a text file. However, for now I think simply having access to the objects per run is fine, thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash table is a great data structure if you need to look things up efficiently (amortized constant time) and conveniently by key.

And a Python `dict` uses a hash table, so it does exactly what you want out of the box. (Of course if you want to build your own hash table as a learning experience, it’s not that hard. But you’re unlikely to get performance as good as the built-in one, especially if you’re using the default CPython interpreter.)

---

Using a `dict` makes your code a lot simpler to write and read. If you make `employees` a `list` of `Employee` objects, to find one by ID you'd have to do this:

```
for employee in employees:
    if employee.id == searchid:
        do_stuff(employee)
        break
```

But if you make if a `dict`, each each `employee` value keyed by its `employee.id`, you can just do this:

```
employee = employees[searchid]
```

(Of course in real-life code, both versions need a bit more to handle the case where an ID isn't found.)

And it's also a lot more efficient. The loop is obviously visiting every employee (well, thanks to the `break`, we're only visiting half of them on average, but still all in the worst case), but the `dict` version is just hashing `searchid` and looking it up in a hash table. So, if you make your table 10000x as big, the `list` version takes 10000x as long, but the `dict` version is still effectively instantaneous.

---

However, if you want to do things like find all employees with `id<=20`, a hash table won’t help for that. Instead, you’d want a sorted collection that you can bisect in logarithmic time.

For static data, where you do all your inserts at the start and then only do queries after that, you can just use a list, `sort(key=operator.attrgetter('id'))` it, then use the `bisect` module for searching.

If you need to frequently add (or delete) entries throughout the lifetime of the system, you want a tree-like data structure—a red-black tree or other balanced binary search tree, or one of the b-tree variants, or a skip list, etc. Python doesn’t come with any of these, but there are nice implementations all over PyPI (or it might be worth building one yourself as an exercise).

There are also some clever hybrid structures that basically act like a rope/deque at small scales but like a b-tree or a wide skip-list at large scales, which can be even better. And these are also available on PyPI.

Comment: What I would like is for the user to be able to select a menu say: Find Emplyee. Then the user will be prompted to enter the Employee's ID. From there the program will search through a (data structure) filled with employee objects check each objects ID to see if it matches the ID entered in by the user.

Comment: @Rob You don’t want to check each object’s ID to see if it matches; the whole point of a hash table is that you just do `employees[id]` and find it in one step (or get a `KeyError` if nobody matches).

Comment: I think I understand. I will mess around with it for a bit. Hopefully, I can figure it out without too much trouble.

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused. So I should be able to find the employee without using a loop?

Comment: Or are you just saying I need to save the objects like {object: object.id} that way when I do loop I am just looking for the id value?

Comment: @Rob The other way around: save them as `{object.id: object}`. Then, you don't do a loop at all. Instead of `for employee in employees: if employee.id == searchid`, you just do `employee = employees[searchid]`.

Comment: Hey I am getting confused. I decided to start a new question. Please feel free to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312587/printing-employee-object-information-from-a-dictonoary-of-employees

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly like time for using a dictionary. Dictionaries in Python use hash tables and are very efficient for searching something with a specific key (ID in your case)